# Fail to run a migration on meteor using mongo's Bulk, Why?

Tags: javascript, meteor, database

I tried to update the `Songs` Collection with the migration below, but it just not work.It loop the `Songs` Collection and update a `songId` to all the document.I use mongo's `Bulk` since there are almost 2000 document inside the `Songs` Collection.

```
import { Songs } from '../imports/api/songs.js';

// omit the version 1

Migrations.add({
  version: 2,
  name: 'update the songId',
  up() {
    // This is how to get access to the raw MongoDB node collection that the Meteor server collection wraps
    const batch = Songs.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

    // Mongo throws an error if we execute a batch operation without actual operations, e.g. when Lists was empty.
    let hasUpdates = false;

    // loop the Songs
    Songs.find({}).forEach(function(song,idx) {
      // add the songId to every song
      batch.find({ _id: song._id }).updateOne({ $set: { songId: idx } });
      hasUpdates = true;
    });

    if (hasUpdates) {
      // We need to wrap the async function to get a synchronous API that migrations expects
      const execute = Meteor.wrapAsync(batch.execute, batch);
      return execute();
    }
    return true;
  },
  down() {
    // the code to down ...
  }
});
```

The Songs Collection's scheme look like that:

```
{ 
  _id: type.mongoId,
  songName: type.string,
  lyric: type.arrayof(type.string),
  ...
}
```

using `meteor v1.5` and `percolate:migrations v1.0.2`,on `Osx`.

But the `Songs` Collection's document `song` still don't have the songId after update to version 2.

Have i did somthing wrong?

Comment: I have no experience with migrations but with meteor development ;) In your case i would consider to use a "native" npm because those have usually more users and therefore maintained. Though this one seems to be active still.

Answer (score 0):

From the `cursor.forEach` [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/):

> `function`
>   `JavaScript`
>   A JavaScript function to apply to each document from the cursor. The `<function>` signature includes **a single argument** that is passed the current document to process.

There is no second argument, so your `idx` is `undefined`, thus `{ $set: { songId: <undefined> } }` has no effect on collection records.

Just add `let idx = 0;` before `Songs.find()`, remove `,idx` from `forEach`'s function signature and replace `songId: idx` with `songId: ++idx`.